# I have a animation for my side navigation that works, but it requires two clicks to fire the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

This code I provided seems to be the only way I figured out how to animate a      side navigation, due to the speed and callback. I want it to toggle back and forth the width of the navigation. I am also wondering if my if statement is written wrong?

```js
$(function(){
  $('.btn').on('click', function(){
 if($('.right-nav').is(':hidden')) {
    $('.right-nav').show()
    $('.right-nav').animate({'width': '350px'}, 'slow');
   } else {
     $('.right-nav').animate({ 'width': '0' }, 'slow', function() {
       $('.right-nav').hide()
     });
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     display: block;
}

.right-nav {
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 4;
     height: 100%;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 0;
     background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right-nav">
  <ul class="navigation-items">
   <li><a class="item" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a class="item" href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
   <li><a class="item" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div> 
<button type="button" class="btn">click me</button>
```

After clicking the button you can see it requires two clicks to initiate the animation from right with a width of 0 animates to a width of 350px. I've searched everywhere for the possible bug I've created.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element is not actually hidden at first because you only moved it off the screen. An element is considered "hidden" when it has been explicitly set that way. So, the first time you click the button, it fails your `if` test and moves into the `else` branch where you do explicitly hide it. Then the second click works.

**Adding `display:none` to the CSS for that element solves the problem.**

```js
$(function(){
  $('.btn').on('click', function(){
 if($('.right-nav').is(':hidden')) {
    $('.right-nav').show()
    $('.right-nav').animate({'width': '350px'}, 'slow');
   } else {
     $('.right-nav').animate({ 'width': '0' }, 'slow', function() {
       $('.right-nav').hide()
     });
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     display: block;
    }

.right-nav {
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 4;
     height: 100%;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 0;
     background-color: white;
        display:none;  /* YOU WEREN'T ACTUALLY HIDING THE ELEMENT */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right-nav">
  <ul class="navigation-items">
   <li><a class="item" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a class="item" href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
   <li><a class="item" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div> 
<button type="button" class="btn">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: none;` to `.right-nav`. You're checking to see if `.right-nav` is `:hidden` before showing it, and it isn't hidden when the page first loads.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     
     $('.btn').on('click', function(){
       if($('.right-nav').is(':hidden')) {
       $('.right-nav').show()
       $('.right-nav').animate({'width': '350px'}, 'slow');
      }
      else {
       
       $('.right-nav').animate({ 'width': '0' }, 'slow', function() {
        $('.right-nav').hide()
       });
      };
     });
    });
```

```css
 
    .item {
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     display: block;
    }


    .right-nav {
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 4;
     height: 100%;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 0;
     background-color: white;
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
          <body>
          <div class="right-nav">
        <ul class="navigation-items">
        <li><a class="item" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a class="item" href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a class="item" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul> 
       </div> 
       

       
     <button type="button" class="btn">click me</button>
            </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I've tried so many different scripts to get it right and was that simple of a display: none..

Comment: @BradVanderbush np!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have to add default condition of your Navigation to hide.
It is taking two clicks because on first click its not getting the state.
Please refer below code.
[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp9yjynw/1/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.right-nav').hide();
          $('.btn').on('click', function(){
              if($('.right-nav').is(':hidden')) {
              $('.right-nav').show()
              $('.right-nav').animate({'width': '350px'}, 'slow');
            }
            else {

              $('.right-nav').animate({ 'width': '0' }, 'slow', function() {
                $('.right-nav').hide()
              });
            };
          });
        });
```